# Exporting tabulated data into an ASCII file preserving column alignment

Tags: export

I have some problems exporting Table data into ASCII files preserving column alignment.

**By example** (under Mathematica v11.2 + Linux):

I generate a random table with 2 columns

```
t = Table[StringJoin[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], RandomInteger[{1,10}]]], 10, 2];
```

> ```
> UOTKRPUOVS   PZFON
> WQSMI        FVAGV
> SGOZQJP      KYWTGIBGF
> B            QEKUEFN
> EKPU         WVIKS
> CHXJBPGXA    BAMYNNG
> FZFXXWZ      TQUYN
> A            K
> ICZFK        MDLKDKIGTD
> NLXH         WVAWTL
> ```

I export it into a Text file with this command:

```
Export["test.txt", t, "Table"]
```

However if I look the exported file (from terminal):

```
cat test.txt
```

I get:

> ```
> UOTKRPUOVS    PZFON
> WQSMI FVAGV
> SGOZQJP   KYWTGIBGF
> B QEKUEFN
> EKPU  WVIKS
> CHXJBPGXA BAMYNNG
> FZFXXWZ   TQUYN
> A K
> ICZFK MDLKDKIGTD
> NLXH  WVAWTL
> ```

-> column alignment is completely lost.

**Fix?:**

The only way I have found so far to fix this issue is to export the table using:

```
Export["test.txt", StringReplace[ToString[Grid[t]], "\n\n" -> "\n"], "Text"]
```

Now,

```
cat test.txt
```

gives me back the right formatting:

> ```
> UOTKRPUOVS   PZFON
> WQSMI        FVAGV
> SGOZQJP      KYWTGIBGF
> B            QEKUEFN
> EKPU         WVIKS
> CHXJBPGXA    BAMYNNG
> FZFXXWZ      TQUYN
> A            K
> ICZFK        MDLKDKIGTD
> NLXH         W
> ```

This works but that seems a very awkward solution for such a basic problem...

Any better idea?

---

**Note:** maybe the `StringReplace[..., "\n\n" -> "\n"]` step is useless under Windows, but I had not the opportunity to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
t = Table[StringJoin[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], RandomInteger[{1, 10}]]],10, 2];  

ToString@Format[TableForm[t, TableSpacing -> {0, 1}], OutputForm]
```

[image]

Then export the string.

Surpisingly it works fine too with arbitrary ragged nested list :

```
    ToString@Format[
  TableForm[{12, s, {2, 6777}, {6, 8, {7, 8}}}, 
   TableSpacing -> {0, 1}, TableAlignments -> {Left, Top, Left}], 
  OutputForm]
```

[image]

This functionality of Mathematica is very old. (Mma 2 at least). It may be supersed by something more modern.

**EDIT**

It is also possible to write directly in a file, like this :

```
st = OpenWrite["test.txt", FormatType ->  OutputForm];
Write[st, TableForm[t, TableSpacing -> {0,1}]];
Close[st];
Import["test.txt"]
```

(* same output as above *)

Comment: (+1) Using `TableForm` for this request is kind of no-brainer, but it did not occur to me! (And I am a [fan of `TableForm`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GridTableForm).)

Comment: @AntonAntonov I'm a fan of TableForm too. In the same spirit as your "gridTableForm", I have created my "flatTableForm" in 2019. The idea was to flatten an arbitrary depth ragged and unbalanced  array in a 2 dimensionnal array without lost of information. The code and some demos are [here].(https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51392005#51392005).

Comment: Cool ! Please, consider submitting a [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository) function.

Answer (score 1):

Slight modifications of the code in the question:

```
t = Table[StringJoin[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], RandomInteger[{1, 10}]]], 10, 4];
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test.txt"}], t, "Table"];
RunProcess[{"cat", FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test.txt"}]}]["StandardOutput"]
```

The following export code might be too ad hoc but works:

```
Clear[AddSpaces]
AddSpaces[col : {_String ..}] :=
  Block[{m = Max@Map[StringLength, col]},
   Map[StringJoin[#, StringJoin @@ Table[" ", m - StringLength[#]]] &,
     col]
   ];

t2 = Transpose[Map[AddSpaces, Transpose[t]]];
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test2.txt"}], t2, "Table"];

RunProcess[{"cat" , FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test2.txt"}]}]["StandardOutput"]
```

[image]

(I strongly suspect there is a solution using the options of `Export`.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was also hoping to find a solution with Export... But I searched for some time without success....

Comment: @PicaudVincent -- Sure, good luck!